# Некорректная картинка в 2d игре на 9 андроиде, unity3d

Tags: android, unity3d, unity3d-android

Скомпилировал свой простенький платформер на unity3d версии 2018.4.16f1 Personal, начал скидывать друзьям и заметил, что у двух из трёх людей у которых 9 андроид, приложение выдаёт вот такую картинку. Приложение успешно устанавливается, после запуска появляется заставка Made with Unity, а при открытии моей главной сцены с игрой вот такая чепуха. На андроидах ниже версией всё работает как надо. Установлена NDK версии r21, SDK вроде все, которые нужны, стоят. Я новичок в Unity, возможно где-то накосячил с sdk, на ПК стоит 8 джава, в Unity в Preferences стоит Use embedded JDK. В чём проблема? Помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Вот что должно отображаться при нормальной работе игры и то, что отображается на 9 андроиде:
[image: 4]
[image: 5]

Параметры в настройках сборки:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Отлаживать конечно не пробовали?

Comment: user7860670, в консоли Unity ни одной ошибки. На моём телефоне всё отлично (у меня 6 андроид). Отладить на телефоне, где она проявляется нет возможности.

Comment: Пробовали ещё эмуляторами проверить? Но как вариант попробуйте собрать проет с дефолтными настройками проекта, там без батчинга и разных настроек на графику. Так же да бы отбросить ошибку в тулзах создайте новый проект и сделайте простую сцену с кубиком на экране, если на тех девайсах все будет ок, то дело в настройках вашего проекта. Если же нет то тогда переустанавливайте студию и юнити.